# Как правильно настроить канал в Golang?

Tags: golang, channels

Подскажите пожалуйста где мне тут поправить, что бы у меня в итоге функции ждали друг друга, main заканчивается и не успевают наполнится мапы

Comment: не понимаю где вы хотите ожидать. тут <-waitChan ?

Comment: используйте sync.WaitGroup для горутин

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач вам нужно использовать инструменты управления жизнью гороутин: контекст и группы ожидания.

В примере мы запускаем приложение и длительный  процесс (10 сек) отдельной гороутиной. Через 5 сек решаем остановить работу этой процесса.
Все это время main ожидает завершения работы процесса, и только после того как это случится - main заканчивает работу.

Если вы заккоментарите строку с `cancel()`, то увидите, что main позволяет доработать процессу до конца.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Application run")

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.TODO())
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    _ = cancel

    wg.Add(1)
    go process(ctx, wg)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    cancel()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Application done")

}

func process(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, params ...interface{}) {

    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Println("Process run")
    counter := 0

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            break
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            counter++
            fmt.Println(counter)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Process done")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nvT5PkQMcr2